# QDK won't run standalone build on some computers

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added QDK to Unity. I compiled the QDK to dlls and copied the dlls into Unity. I have it working great on my computer. The issue is when I run it on another computer it doesn't start the simulator. Through testing I have found that I have to have Visual Studios installed on the computer to make it work. I think I am missing a dependency that is needed by QDK that gets installed with VS. I am not sure on how to go about figuring out which dependencies I need. How would I figure this out? Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit? @Kobaltic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure this out. Someone recommended using a VM for testing. This was a great suggestion and allowed me to work much quicker and I can test different operating systems.

I figured out if I had the c++ redistributables installed everything worked correctly. I found where the dlls are stored on my computer. I copied them to my project in Unity and it fixed my issue. It now works correctly.